# How to get the digits from an int value and append it into an array

Tags: c

I want to append the number(value) digit by digit into the destination array but how would I iterate "i" backwards? I am saying this because I want to use v / 10^i % 10 which would get me the digit of any place I want using i where i = 0 is the low order digit and v is the value. Here is what I did so far:

```
value = va_arg( ap, int); 
       //value is the int value
       while(value > 0) {
          unsigned int digit1 = value / pow(10,i) % 10

          append( &dest, &len, &cap, digit1 + 048);

       }
```

The append part can be ignored since it doesn't relate to the problem except the last parameter. The last parameter is expecting a character. I have not set "i" since I am not sure how to iterate i. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The number of digits will be the smallest integer greater than `log10(value)`. So you know exactly what elements of your array will be filled.

Alternately, you could form your array incrementally and then reverse it if you want it in the opposite order.

Comment: But how would your first statement help me with the formula: v / 10^i % 10?

Answer (score 0):

Some code like below would work w/o using library functions.

```
int value = 234873485;
int digit;
int tmpValue = value;
int i = 0;
int arr[10] = {0};

while (tmpValue > 1) {
    tmpValue /= 10;
    i++;
}

tmpValue = value;

while (tmpValue > 1) {
    digit = tmpValue % 10;
    printf("%d\n", digit); // may be replaced to append array
    arr[i--] = digit;      // something like this one
    tmpValue /= 10;
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't help me with my problem. I am trying to get the digits and then store them into an array using the append function I have which allows character by character input.

Comment: Well, then you have to replace `int arr[]` to `char arr[]` and modify the append line as  `arr[i--] = digit + '0';`.